# ViewModel property is NULL when sent to Main View - Asp.Net Core MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a ViewModel (FilialViewModel) that has a property of type PessoaViewModel. The main View is tied to FilialViewModel and whenever I submit, the property of type PessoaViewModel is NULL. This is because when I call PartialView Person, I pass FilialViewModel.PersonaViewModel ... When submitting, only the fields of FilialViewModel ... are loaded. Does anyone know how to solve this?

```
public class FilialViewModel
{
    [Key]
    public int PessoaFilialId { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Tipo de Filial")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Escolha um Tipo de Filial")]
    public FilialTipo FilialTipo { get; set; }

    public PessoaViewModel PessoaViewModel { get; set; }

}

public class PessoaViewModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Natureza")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Escolha uma Natureza")]
    public PessoaNatureza PessoaNatureza { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Natureza")]
}
```

View Filial:

```
@model Retaguarda.Application.ViewModels.Filial.FilialViewModel
@{

}

<div class="panel">
    <div class="panel-body container-fluid pt-5 pl-15 pr-15">
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <vc:summary />
           @await Html.PartialAsync("~/Views/Pessoa/_Pessoa.cshtml", Model.PessoaViewModel)
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

View Pessoa:

```
@model Retaguarda.Application.ViewModels.Pessoa.PessoaViewModel
@using Retaguarda.Domain.Enuns.Pessoa
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Pessoa";
}

@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id, new { @class = "hidden-id" })
<div class="col-md-2">
    <label asp-for="PessoaNatureza" class="control-label">Natureza</label>
    <select id="pessoaNatureza" data-modal="" asp-for="PessoaNatureza" asp-items="Model.PessoasNaturezas" title="Selecione uma opção" class="form-control"><option value=""></option></select>
    <span asp-validation-for="PessoaNatureza" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize(Policy = "CanWriteFilialData")]
[Route("filial-gerenciar/cadastrar-novo")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Create(FilialViewModel filialViewModel)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) return View(filialViewModel);
    _filialAppService.Register(filialViewModel);

    if (IsValidOperation())
        ViewBag.Sucesso = "Filial cadastrada!";
    // return Json(new { success = true, message = "Pessoa Excuída!" });
    return View(filialViewModel);

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your issue, you need to pass `FilialViewModel` instead of `PessoaViewModel`

Follow steps below:

1. Model

   ```
   public class FilialViewModel
   {
       [Key]
       public int PessoaFilialId { get; set; }

       public PessoaViewModel PessoaViewModel { get; set; }

   }

   public class PessoaViewModel
   {
       [Key]
       public int Id { get; set; }

       [DisplayName("Natureza")]
       [Required(ErrorMessage = "Escolha uma Natureza")]
       public string PessoaNatureza { get; set; }
       public List<SelectListItem> PessoasNaturezas { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. View

   ```
   @model FilialViewModel
   @{

   }
   <div class="panel">
       <form method="post">
           <div class="panel-body container-fluid pt-5 pl-15 pr-15">
               <div class="form-horizontal">
                   @await Html.PartialAsync("~/Views/Pessoa/_Pessoa.cshtml", Model)
               </div>
           </div>
           <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
       </form>

   </div>
   ```
3. Partial View

   ```
   @model FilialViewModel

   @{
       ViewData["Title"] = "Pessoa";
   }

   @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PessoaViewModel.Id, new { @class = "hidden-id" })
   <div class="col-md-2">
       <label asp-for="PessoaViewModel.PessoaNatureza" class="control-label">Natureza</label>
       <select id="pessoaNatureza" data-modal="" asp-for="@Model.PessoaViewModel.PessoaNatureza" asp-items="@Model.PessoaViewModel.PessoasNaturezas" title="Selecione uma opção" class="form-control"><option value=""></option></select>
       <span asp-validation-for="@Model.PessoaViewModel.PessoaNatureza" class="text-danger"></span>
   </div>
   ```

Note, for `PessoaNatureza`, you need to define the property which accept the filed instead of a object like `PessoaNatureza`.

Comment: Hi @Tao Zhou! The problem is that PessoaViewModel will also be used with other ViewModels besides FilialViewModel, such as CustomersViewModel and FuncinarioViewModel. I have to do this without passing a FilialViewModel ... It has to be PessoaViewModel. I tried using a hidden and saving PessoaViewModel, but it didn't work :(

Comment: @MasterJR If you insist on passing `PessoaViewModel`, try to provider name attribute like `<select id="pessoaNatureza" name="PessoaViewModel.PessoaNatureza" data-modal="" asp-for="@Model.PessoaNatureza" asp-items="@Model.PessoasNaturezas" title="Selecione uma opção" class="form-control"><option value=""></option></select>`